SingleStore Array field in SqlAlchemy
Singlestore supports arrays/vectors.
SqlAlchemy has arrays/lists in postgres for example.
Is there any such support for Singlestore?

Yes. SingleStore does support the ARRAY data type in its SQL syntax. Arrays in SingleStore consist of an ordered set of elements where each element must have the same data type.
